# c++ input for-loop followed by another input

Tags: c++, for-loop, input

c++ Microsoft visual studio on a windows.

im very new to coding. currently going through Programming -- Principles and Practice Using C++ by Stroupstrup and I came across a difficulty. I am  to create a "score chart" with vector name and vector score from the user input. I used for-loop to get the input. now I am to modify the program so that with 2nd input from the user I can search the list and "cout<<" the score for a person. the problem is the the program completely ignores the 2nd "cin>>" command.
 I search online and could not find a reasonable answer to this problem. Is there any special interaction between a for-loop input being terminated and another input (not looped)
syntax:

```
  #include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
vector<string> name;
vector<int> score;
string temp2;
int i;
for (string temp; cin >> temp >> i;) //input terminated with "Ctrl+Z"
    name.push_back(temp), score.push_back(i);
for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i) {
    for (int j = i + 1; j < name.size(); ++j) {
        if (name[i] == name[j]) {
            name[j] = "error";
            score[j] = 0;
        }
    }
}
for (int i = 0; i < name.size(); ++i) {
    cout << name[i] << "------" << score[i] << "\n";
}
cout << "name"; //this line shows in the console
cin >> temp2; //but I cannot prompt the user to input again?
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`CTRL-Z` is interpreted as "End-Of-File", such that any subsequent access to this stream will not read in items any more. The only secure way is to change program logic such that the list of names is terminated by, let's say "END", and not a `CTRL-Z`. Then you can continue in a save manner.

Often input from a terminal is read in line by line and parsed afterwards. This makes error handling easier. See the following code following such an approach:

```
#include <sstream>

int main() {

    string line;
    map<string,int> scoreboard;
    cout << "enter name score (type END to finish):" << endl;

    while (std::getline(cin, line) && line != "END") {
        stringstream ss(line);
        string name;
        int score;
        if (ss >> name >> score) {
            scoreboard[name] = score;
        } else {
            cout << "invalid input. Type END to finish" << endl;
        }
    }

    cout << "enter name:" << endl;
    string name;
    if (cin >> name) {
        auto item = scoreboard.find(name);
        if (item != scoreboard.end()){
            cout << "score of " << name << ":" << item->second << endl;
        }
        else {
            cout << "no entry for " << name << "." << endl;
        }
    }


}
```